# Suggestions for image hosting

Tags: discussion, images

I think it'd be useful to have a list of suggested sites on which to host images (e.g. diagrams) used in questions and answer.

Comment: [See this question on webapps.](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/925/which-photo-storage-sites-allow-for-hot-linking)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[imgFTW](http://imgftw.net/) ([extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ndncfjacolimobaaciaaapeldkciolig))

Answer (score 2):

[Imgur](http://imgur.com/) ([extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/naicjelodgogagjjkgepdkjecopegkag))

Comment: I put a [diagram on imgur](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13820/how-many-combinatorial-types-of-pure-quadtopes-of-dimension-5-are-there) on 18 January 2011 & it disappeared recently. Should I try it again?

Comment: @Dan: Did you use the image-upload button built into the editor now?  That'd be what I'd try next, if you hadn't done it that way before.

Comment: I'm guessing the diagram timed out, as the imgur FAQ says it has to be viewed at least once every six months or it will be deleted. I didn't see or use the button - I copy pasted the new link onto the old link.

Comment: Given that SE network now supports interal image hosting with *stable* URL, all existing answers pointing to external image hosts should be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

[Flickr](http://flickr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Stack Exchange's internal image uploader](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uploader)

[Disallow new embedded images from hosts other than the SE imgur account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231613)

[Why does Stack Exchange use Imgur to host images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350433)

Answer (score -1):

[Picasa](http://picasaweb.google.com)

Answer (score -1):

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) (use its public folder feature)

<sub>[Link with referral (+250 MB)](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTExNjQ0MTQ5)</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure I trust dropbox with high volume traffic.  But then again, how high volume could this get?