# Logo ideas/proposals

Tags: discussion, poll, top-7, user-interface

Right now, math.stackexchange has the same look as every other beta SE 2.0 site. However, we will eventually need our own logo. Please post as answers below, your logo proposals for this site. One per answer please.

Rules:
Not copyrighted
Should be vectorizable

Having it linked to a specific [name proposal](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-domain-name-to-use) could make sense.

See [suggestions for image hosting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/suggestions-for-image-hosting) if you need someplace to put your idea.

Comment: I will leave my suggestions out, but when the time comes and we have picked a name, I would be willing to make the logo. I have some experience with these kind of things.(Of course we can vote on the actual logo)

Answer (score 6):

I suggested [**ForAllQThereExistsA.com**](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-domain-name-to-use/333#333). A decorative rendering of "∀Q∃A" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

So, I half-jokingly suggested [coffeIntoTheorems.com](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-domain-name-to-use/286#286), but a logo could look like this:

$\box \to \forall \varepsilon>0$

replacing $\box$ with a little coffee mug, and then put something 'mathy' that the coffee cup is being mapped into.  (Maybe $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ is a bit too analysis-centric)

Answer (score 4):

If we do wind up settling on [MathExchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-domain-name-to-use/45#45), some sort of [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) next to/ underneath part of the name itself would be pretty canonical.

Answer (score 1):

For the name [**planeAndSimple.com**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-domain-name-to-use/290#290), a picture of the [Fano plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) might be suitable, if someone is willing to draw a vectorized one.

Comment: Actually, I think it could go well with a variety of names, but my logo idea did cause me to suggest that one.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather http://imgur.com/4UYRf.png or http://imgur.com/LMx1J.png they are bigger badder projective planes. :D

Comment: @BBischof: They are, and that's why I don't think they'd be as good for a logo. But feel free to post the picture separately and let people vote on it.

Comment: I was mostly just trying to be funny. :)

Answer (score 0):

My MathOverflow logo is the Jacobi symbol: (math/flow).

So MathUnderflow should have the symbol: (flow/math).

The trick is to work out their higher reciprocity laws! Akhil?